# Injecting css inside the head from javascript is not loading completely

Tags: html, css, shady-dom

```
const cssJs ='/*here comes my css - the css here is 200kb in size*/';
function CSSString2CSSStyleSheet ( cssJs ) {
const style = document.createElement ( 'style' );
style.innerText = cssJs;
style.title = 'cssJs';
document.head.appendChild ( style );
const {sheet} = style;
return sheet;
}
CSSString2CSSStyleSheet ( cssJs );
```

The code above is adding a style tag with css from JS and the css is passed to the style tag innerText. But only the half of the css are injected. At the end of the half css ... is added.

Comment: what is this supposed to be/intent here for this syntactically incorrect code? `{sheet}`  FWIW Injecting a new style element this way is going to cause your page to re-flow.  Perhaps describe what you are REALLY trying to do/goal here is.

Comment: Is this a templating attempt?

Comment: Trying to inject the css into the style tag, rather than calling the css inside the <link> tag. So that the css will load the page fast from head tag and the page also be less weight. By this method even if we see the pages viewsource, the injected styles wont be visible.

Comment: That's not how it works. The performance will be lower as it can't be cached. Besides that, those styles are not directly visible but still visible to anyone that is interested in them. Everything that is accesses by the browser (including JS) can be read by any half-decent developer from the dev tools.

Comment: One can still see the style in the browser developer tools. Everything you try must result in valid CSS, so this can't be prevented. Just put the styles in one big file. This is cached by the browser once for every page, instead of putting styles in your JavaScript AND in your styles.

Comment: Also, the only minor difference between including it in your JS and including it a a seperate CSS file is a minimal amount of headers, otherwise the amount of bytes is still as long as your CSS is, but you just made things hard on yourself. Also, the code provided should work (though heed the advice given), but you don't show us CSS so it's very well possible it's not showing half of it because your CSS is malformed or incorrect - we have no way to know or help you with that.